# Python and win32com.client seem to be missing methods, in particular SetSourceData

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm working on using Python to automate some Excel data analysis. I have most of the basics down, but I can't seem to find any way to call `SetSourceData` or `SeriesCollection` successfully. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339115/python-extra-excel-chart-series-with-win32com) (and all the others) and found it hopeful, but it doesn't seem to match my experience. I'm using Python 2.7.3, 32 bit on a Windows machine.

Has anyone successfully used `SetSourceData` or `SeriesCollection`?

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using and the error:

```
chart = chartSheet.ChartObjects(1)

chart.SetSourceData(chartSheet.Range("A1:B2"),PlotBy=2)
```

I specify `PlotBy` because of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178843%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I doubt it matters

And the error:

```
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))

AttributeError: '&lt;win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.ChartObject instance at 0x68557120&gt;' object has no attribute 'SetSourceData'
```

ARGH. Should I look into IronPython? (I've found a few other things that are specified in the MSDN documentation but don't seem to work in Python... but can't remember them now.)

Comment: `win32com` is great, but the [python excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) modules might make life easier for you..

Comment: Actually, I use both. To the extent I can, I use the Python excel modules, but one of my main goals is the creation of a "paper trail" of Excel objects (namely charts and tables) that non-programmers can view and edit, when the program falls short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
chart = chartSheet.ChartObjects(1)
```

doesn't actually return a `Chart` object ([quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chartsheet.chartobjects.aspx))

> This method is not equivalent to the Charts property. This method returns embedded charts; the Charts property returns chart sheets. Use the Chart property to return the Chart object for an embedded chart.

I haven't tried this, but it sounds as if you need to reference the `chart` attribute, maybe like this:

```
chartObject = chartSheet.ChartObjects(1)
chart = chartObject.chart
```

Comment: ACK! Thank you! That did it exactly.